# CodeIgniter 3.1.9 - Cannot identify the problem with login form validation

Tags: php, validation, view, controller, codeigniter-3

I'm using codeigniter 3.1.9 to create a login form using a html helper and form_validation library for its validation.
For validating the input fields i'm using `set_rules('input name, 'relative name', 'required')` function in the controller and for displaying the errors i'm using `validation_errors('your div for showing the errors')` function in the view.
Also i'm using `set_value('input name')` function for setting their input values but i'm unable to see the success message that i have passed from the controller and also the validation errors doesn't seem to go after i hit the submit button which exists on top right after the form tag even if the input fields are not empty.

Please find the link for the screenshot of the source code below and provide me any solution to indentify the actual problem with the code. Thank you

[Link to see the source code of the controller & view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0HqR.jpg)

Comment: form_validation library should be loaded, But you have commented that line in the screen shot what you have shared.

Comment: Yes, actually i'm autoloading the form_validation library from there itself. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

- Used two same attributes in the input field of your form which is not correct.
- Form validation is run by the name attribute.
- `Removing them will correct the form validation`

> Login Controller

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_pass', 'Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login');
        } else {
            echo "Form Submit.";
        }
    }
}
```

> View File

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo set_value('user_email'); ?>">
    <input type="password"" name="user_pass" value="<?php echo set_value('user_pass'); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```